# Alternative calling convention for x86

Tags: x86, calling-convention

Is it possible to create an alternative calling convention without modifying the compiler itself? This hypothetical calling convention could , for instance, be used for optimization

Comment: Can you be more specific in what you need?   It seems unlikely, given that calling conventions act at a low level and the compiler will impose its own.

Comment: @cdarke Well, I was analyzing some assembly code and came across some nonstandard calling conventions which apparently are used for either optimization or obfuscation, so I wonder  how one would go about writing one of those

Comment: Assembly code - exactly.  That's the level you would need to work at, not C.

Comment: It is all up to the developers of the compilers. For instance OpenWatcom C/C++ allows you to actually define new calling conventions. using [`#pragma aux`](http://tuttlem.github.io/2015/10/04/inline-assembly-with-watcom.html) . They are nonstandard extensions to the language to allow for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc / clang have their knowledge of calling conventions compiled in to the compiler executable, not defined by a config file you could override without recompiling the compiler.

So yes you'd need to modify the compiler, but it might not be hard for the open-source compilers.  The gcc-internals documentation has [a whole chapter on stack layout and calling conventions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Register-Arguments.html#Register-Arguments), documenting how calling conventions are described to the compiler.  It looks like this is done in C source code, not in a special language the way machine-definition files describe the instruction-set to the compiler.

I didn't check how clang / LLVM defines calling conventions.

---

But there is some limited flexibility in some cases with GNU C (gcc/clang/ICC).  It's not great, but it's not totally fixed.

On x86, the compilers know about multiple existing calling conventions.  e.g. x86-64 System V and Windows have different calling conventions, and you can use `__attribute__((ms_abi))` to declare a function that uses the Windows convention, even when compiled for a non-Windows target platform.  When compiling calls to functions, gcc of course generates code to pass args and set up the stack according to the calling convention declared for the function.

For 32-bit x86, there are many conventions.  See the [gcc docs for function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html).

e.g. you can use  `__attribute__((fastcall)) void foo(int a, int b) { ... }` to declare a function that expects it args in ECX and EDX, instead of on the stack.

There's even support (on 32-bit x86) for setting the max number of register arguments for a calling convention, with `__attribute((regparm(3)))` to declare a function that takes up to 3 integer args in registers instead of the stack.  But the sequence of registers is not configurable, and it only uses EAX, ECX, and EDX (the registers that are call-clobbered in most conventions).

You can also compile with `-mregparm=2` to set this globally.

But there's no support for declaring functions to be called with shadow space (like x64 Windows), or with caller-pops (except for some specific caller-pops conventions), or with boolean results returned in FLAGS instead of an integer register, or any of the other stuff you can do with hand-written assembly.

---

MSVC similarly supports some `__declspec` options for vectorcall vs. regular.